# Download Binary from WebApi2 As File. Server Side

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2, binaryfiles

I've looked a couple of answers on here but still having an issue.
One system is saving a binary byte[] into SQL 2014 with Entity Framework 6.

I have a "name" of the record (not the file) but I want to serve up the binary data as a downloadable file via the webapi2. I have it somewhat working but on the browser it shows the ID as the file name and says can't download file. It is prompting to download but then it can't.

Right now for PoC I'm hard coding the mime type to word docs. What am I doing wrong and how should I refactor this to also provide a file name.

I'm saving the document using Office Apps, Task Pane:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj715284.aspx

FileType: "*Compressed*" = Returns the entire document (.pptx or .docx) in Office Open XML (OOXML) format as a byte array.

```
Office.context.document.getSelectedDataAsync(Office.CoercionType.Text,
            function (result) {
                if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
                    vm.data.data = result.value;
                    //I call a angularJs service which post..
                   //return $http.post('https://stapi.local:8443/api/activities', vm.data);

                } else {

                }
            }
        );
```

Then I try to let a user download the document with the following.

**WebAPI2 Controller:**

```
[HttpGet, Route("api/activityObjectFile/{id}/{name}")]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetDataFile(int id)
        {
            var fileByte = _activityService.GetFile(id);
            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage { Content = new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(fileByte))};
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/msword");
            response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = fileByte.Length;
            response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment filename=test.docx");

            return response;
        }
```

**Class Service Library:**

```
public Byte[] GetFile(int id)
        {
            var existingActivityObjectFile = _repo.QueryAll<ActivityObject>().Where(a => a.Id == id).Select(a => a.BinaryData).First();

            return existingActivityObjectFile;
        }
```

**Client Url:**

```
<a href="http://stapi.local/api/activityObjectFile/14">Download</a>
```

Comment: With the above Client Url, the file will always take the name of your end URL segment.  For test purposes can you attempt to add an arbitrary file name after the `/activityObjectFile/14` for example: `activityObjectFile/14/test.docx`.  Your WebAPI2 Controller appears to have the route setup to accept a file name as part of the route, but it does not appear that you are utilizing it.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you going for now:

```
var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) 
{ 
   Content = new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(fileByte))        
};
response.Content
        .Headers
        .Add("Content-Type", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") 
{ 
   FileName = "test.docx" 
};
return response;
```

As for suggestions for refactoring, you could use my method.

I have an implementation of the `IHttpActionResult` that I return, it looks like this:

```
public class DocumentAttachmentResult : IHttpActionResult {
    private readonly string fileName;
    private readonly string mimeType;
    private readonly byte[] blob;

    public DocumentAttachmentResult(string fileName, string mimeType, byte[] blob) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.mimeType = mimeType;
        this.blob = blob;
    }

    private HttpResponseMessage Execute() {
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) { Content = new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(this.blob)) };
        response.Content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", this.mimeType);
        response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") { FileName = this.fileName };
        return response;
    }

    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
        return Task.FromResult(this.Execute());
    }
}
```

And my controller action looks like this:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("attachments/{id:guid}/download")]
    public IHttpActionResult DownloadAttachment(Guid id) {
        var attachment = this.repository.FindById(id);
        if (attachment == null) {
            return this.NotFound();
        }
        return new DocumentAttachmentResult(attachment.Name, attachment.FileType.MimeType, attachment.BinaryBlob);
    }
```

I store the file name, mime type and binary in SQL server have it modeled as one entity called `Attachment`. The mime type and file is captured when I upload a file using another action on my *WebApi* controller.

Comment: I tried that, I seem to have the same problem. The browser want's to save file "14" which is the ID I sent in, and when I try and save in the IE download manager, it says "This file couldn't be downloaded."

Comment: @Mastro what version of IE are you using? Also in your content disposition header you are missing a semi colon after attachment, it should be `attachment; filename=test.docx`

Comment: On this machine it's poping up on Microsoft Edge (Windows 10) machine. Let me go try my Windows 8 (IE) machine.

Comment: Ok tried it on my other machine and IE crashes. Maybe it has to do with the way I'm saving it. I'm using  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj715284.aspx to save the binary data from Word. File Type "compressed". I'm assuming it's the Open XML minetype you have.

Comment: I'm using Anish Patel's code now. Same issue though, thinking it has something to do with the byte[] data maybe.

Comment: Even it we say it's the way it's saved, the download still pops us as the ID as the download name, something wrong with it.